# How to get clean output of package.json module run script ( either with yarn or npm run )?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a project that gets encrypted config from a git repo, decrypts and creates bash export statements that work the config into env vars:

https://github.com/browsercapturesalt/config

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@browsercapturesalt/config

When run with `node_modules/@browsercapturesalt/config/bin/env`, the output looks like this:

```
export X=y
export FOO=bar
```

I can do `eval $(node_modules/@browsercapturesalt/config/bin/env)` and it works my config into env vars.

If I have in `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
 "env": "env"
}
```

and try to run it with `yarn env`, the output is

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ env
export X=y
export FOO=bar
Done in 0.44s.
```

So `eval $(yarn env)` does not work because of all the garbage logging. Same goes for `npm run`, the logs are different, but still break bash interpreter.

As you cannot set parent terminal env vars with a process, I see no other way than to source it.

Is there a way I can get the clean output of this command without having to type in the whole `node_modules` path?

Answer (score 2):

I think the option `--silent` should solve your problem.

Could you try: `yarn --silent env`

Comment: While this works for yarn v1, the `--silent` flag was removed in yarn v2. It's unclear how to do this nicely in yarn 2 or 3.